# Add a day to a date in Progress OpenEdge db query

Tags: progress-database

I am looking for a way to increment a date value by one day in Progress OpenEdge DB query. I am using the OpenEdge SQL-92 query engine rather than the ABL (4gl) engine.

Something similar to how one might do it for a SQL server query would be ideal:

```
     --first attempt
     SELECT DateAdd("d",1,EffDate) 
     FROM pub.pv_currrates

     --another attempt does not work 
     SELECT ADD-INTERVAL(b.BillDate, days, 1) AS one_day_back
     ...
```

UPDATE:
I found [this](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-reference-117/page/ADD-INTERVAL-function.html) add-interval function, but we can't seem to get it to work correctly.

Comment: ADD-INTERVAL() is an ABL function, it is not available to SQL.  SQL functions are documented here: https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-sql-reference-117/page/OpenEdge-SQL-Functions.html

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. It came up in many of my searches and I couldn't get it to work. Good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out. As I am not used to this way to add dates in this RDBMS, I figure I should post this so everyone may know.

```
 SELECT EffDate+1
 FROM pub.pv_currrates
```

[Reference](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-sql-reference-117/page/Date-arithmetic-expressions.html).